# Connect Azure Front Door to AKS Cluster Multi-region and multi-service

Tags: azure-aks, azure-front-door

I have the below scenario to implement using FrontDoor and AKS.

I have 2 AKS clusters in different Azure regions - eastus and westus. There are 2 services running in both the clusters - service1, service2. Both the services use a standard load balancer and have an external IP and DNS. But we have some NSG rules on the Azure subscription to not allow access from public internet.

I want to set up a front door, and use it for both, redirecting traffic to a region, and using routing rules to further redirect traffic to one of the services within the AKS cluster.

This is my current setup. All resources are in the same subscription and resource group -

I have a FrontDoor: fd-test, with endpoint fd-test.z01.azurefd.net.
In the origin groups, I add 2 groups - service1-group and service2-group. service1-group contains 2 custom origins - service1.eastus.cloudapp.azure.com, service1.westus.cloudapp.azure.com. Similarly, service2-group contains the eastus and westus FQDN of service2 running in both the clusters. The eastUS FQDN in both groups is given priority 1 and westus is given priority 2. Further, I have added routing rules to say if the path contains '/service1/' then forward the request to service1-group and if the path contains '/service2/' then forward the request to service2-group.

This should work to redirect traffic to the group of the correct service, and choose eastus based on priority, and in case eastus is down, redirect to westus, isn't it?

I have not setup any certificate-name validation or enforcing HTTPS yet.

On calling 'http://fd-test.z01.azurefd.net/service2', I receive an error
[image]
[image]

What do I need to change for authentication? On directly calling the service, the bearer token is working, so with front door, the authentication should still happen at the service, right?

UPDATE
On making the call via HTTP, I'm receiving a 503 - Service Unavailable